# split function in lists and leave out some observations

Tags: r, list, split, lapply, ceil

this is my code:

```
cpi <- c(100:200)
cpi_sp <- seq_along(cpi) 
cpis <- list(cpi, c(100:200), c(100:200), c(100:200))
cpis_y <- lapply(cpis, function(x) split(x, ceiling(cpi_sp/12)) )
```

I would like that `split` resp. `ceiling` do their job for the first e.g. 4 observations and then always for the next 12. I know there is a simple way, but I couldn't find it until now. thanks for helping!

Comment: What's the desired result?

Comment: DId you meant `lapply(cpis, function(x) split(x, c(rep(0, 4), ceiling(cpi_sp[-(1:4)]/12))))`

Comment: yes this was the solution! please post this as answer and i will accept it! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted by akrun is:

```
lapply(cpis, function(x) split(x, c(rep(0, 4), ceiling(cpi_sp[-(1:4)]/12))))
```